# Android - Changing app language for all versions of Android

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, locale

I tried a few ways to change the locale of the android app, but when I test my app on Android 7.0 or lower, the locale is not changed.

**Note: The ways worked on Android 8.0 or upper, but they didn't work on Android 7.0 or lower.**

Which way does work on all of the Android versions?
Do you know?

The ways that I tried:

- [The first way](https://devdeeds.com/android-change-language-at-runtime)
- [The second way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-app-language-programmatically-in-android)
- [The third way](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ywF-ySiBAsc)

**Note: I tested my app on Galaxy Tab S2 with Android 7.0 (Didn't work). And on a Galaxy A5 2017 with Android 8.0 (Worked).**

**Note: Many of my activities wrote in Kotlin.**

My codes:

**Locale Helper class:**

```
public class LocaleHelper {

private static final String SELECTED_LANGUAGE = "Locale.Helper.Selected.Language";

public static Context onAttach(Context context) {
    String lang = getPersistedData(context, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
    return setLocale(context, lang);
}

public static Context onAttach(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
    String lang = getPersistedData(context, defaultLanguage);
    return setLocale(context, lang);
}

public static String getLanguage(Context context) {
    return getPersistedData(context, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
}

public static Context setLocale(Context context, String language) {
    persist(context, language);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        return updateResources(context, language);
    }

    return updateResourcesLegacy(context, language);
}

private static String getPersistedData(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    return preferences.getString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, defaultLanguage);
}

private static void persist(Context context, String language) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

    editor.putString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, language);
    editor.apply();
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
private static Context updateResources(Context context, String language) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(language);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);

    Configuration configuration = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
    configuration.setLocale(locale);

    return context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private static Context updateResourcesLegacy(Context context, String language) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(language);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);

    Resources resources = context.getResources();

    Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
    configuration.locale = locale;

    resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());

    return context;
}
```

}

**attachBaseContext method(I put these codes at all of my activities):**

```
override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context?) {
    super.attachBaseContext(LocaleHelper.onAttach(base, "en"))
}
```

**Changing locale method(To Persian):**

```
LocaleHelper.setLocale(getContext(), "fa")
```

Comment: Mention, what you have tried.

Comment: Did you create different resource files based on locale?

Comment: Thanks for your attention - I added the list of ways that I tried for you.

Comment: Thanks for your attention - Yeah I created the resources that I want to switch on those.

Comment: default lang of your app is "en", isn't it? if it is, you need to put Persian resources in the string value of en and vice versa for English resources.

Comment: Why? Is it solve my problem?
You mean I should change "fa" resources as the Default value and make an "en" resources, too?

Answer (score 3):

You should create a base activity for example and override `onConfigurationChange` method on that, set the default language that you saved in shared preferences. After all you have to extend your activities from base activity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. - I did it, but I used the attachBaseContext method in all of the Activities.
Should I use onConfigurationChange?

Comment: if you extended all activities from BaseActivity, you should not although it's a better way.
if you don't you should override attachBaseContext.

Comment: Can you say that easier, please?

Comment: I mean, when the user changes locale in your application all activities should reset, and in attachBaseContext, you should do that (setLocale()). if you extend all activities from the base activity you don't need override attachBaseContext because you just need to reset main activity. ok?

Comment: OK. I see. Thank you, Mostafa, I'm gonna try to do the thing that you point that.
By the way, I will tell you the result.

Comment: I did it Mostafa.
Here is my code: 
override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context?) {
        super.attachBaseContext(LocaleHelper.onAttach(base, "en"))
    }

Comment: so what was the result?

Comment: Don't work. I did it at first.
But now it isn't working on Android 7.0 or lower either.

Comment: Yeah. I'm gonna add my code to the desc of my question.